# Content-Disposition header different from Nginx to Apache

Tags: apache, http, http-headers, apache2

I am building a Symfony application involving downloads of PDF files.

When returning a response for the  file download I am setting the Content-Disposition header with a filename.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"
```

I have been running this on my development machine using Nginx and when debugging the response in Chrome I can see that the header is set correctly. But after moving this to a test machine running Apache the header just shows up as:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
```

Can this have anything to do with Apache? Source code is identical.

I should tell that the filename I am setting in the header is not the actual filename, but I see no difference when using the actual filename.

Here's the Symfony snippet that is setting the header:

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $name . '"');
```

Comment: Can you paste the section in your code that is setting said header? Also: Is the *resourcename* equal to the filename you're setting?